# Limit of Quotient of Two C infinity Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that f and g are two functions that are $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $k$ be a positive integer, and suppose that 
$$f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=\ldots=f^{(k)}(0)=0$$ 
and 
$$
g(0)=g'(0)=g''(0)=\ldots=g^{(k)}(0)=0.$$ 
Assuming that $g^{(k+1)}(0)\neq0$, show that 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{g^{(k+1)}(0)}
$$

I have no idea where to start with this. I am not allowed to use L'Hopital's rule. I know that $C^{\infty}$ functions are differentiable for any degree of differentiation, so the $(k+1)$ derivative must exist for both $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Can you use Taylor polynomials?

Comment: Hi, @britgirl5.  I've edited your question to add proper formatting of the display math.  Please make sure it matches your intentions; feel free to take a look at the source to see how I did it, too. :-)

Comment: @NickPeterson Thank you!

Comment: @mfl Yes I think I am supposed to use Taylor polynomials somehow but I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hypothesis you have that

$$f(x)=\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}+o(x^{k+1})$$ and

$$g(x)=\dfrac{g^{(k+1)}}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}+o(x^{k+1}).$$ Thus

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}& 
\\ &=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}+o(x^{k+1})}{\dfrac{g^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}+o(x^{k+1})}
\\ &=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}+\dfrac{o(x^{k+1})}{x^{k+1}}}{\dfrac{g^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}+\dfrac{o(x^{k+1})}{x^{k+1}}}
\\ &=\dfrac{\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}+\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{o(x^{k+1})}{x^{k+1}}}{\dfrac{g^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}+\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{o(x^{k+1})}{x^{k+1}}}
\\ &=\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{g^{(k+1)}(0)}.\end{align}

Comment: What is the last term in the first line? Is that the remainder?

Comment: Yes, it is. You have that $f(x)=P_n(x)+R_n(x).$ And what is important to solve this question is that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{R_n(x)}{x^n}=0.$ That's the reason I have used the $o$-notation.